# How can I optimize this query to delete records that have no corresponding Id in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, query-optimization, sql-delete

I have a "Main" table of half a million records which contains a primary key Id (MovieId) that is used by several other tables as a foreign key (many-to-many tables).

Some of these many-to-many tables have millions of records (up to 20 million).

I want to remove all of the records from the many-to-many tables whose foreign key does not exist in the main table. This will reduce their size tremendously (down to "only" a million or two million records each).

But the SQL to accomplish this seems as if it will be very time consuming - essentially looping over 20 million records, each time looking through up to half a million records in the main table to see if the foreign key in the 20 million many-to-many table records exists in the half million main table records as a primary key.

I can imagine this taking a LONG time. Is there a (relatively) quick way to do this?

My first idea to accomplish this is something like:

```
DELETE FROM ACTORS_MOVIES_M2M
WHERE MovieiD NOT EXISTS (SELECT MovieiD FROM MOVIES_MAIN)
```

...and again, I perceive this will take ... a WHILE.

Comment: That code doesn''t parse.

Answer (score 1):

The query you wanted to write:

```
delete m2m 
from actors_movies_m2m m2m
where not exists (select 1 from movies_main m where m.movieid = m2m.movieid)
```

An index on `movies_main(movieid)` would help the subquery to execute quickly (provided that `movieid` is the primary key of `movies_main`, it is already there).

While this is technically correct, this might not be the most efficient approach. If you are going to delete a significant part of the table, then it might be more efficient to empty and refill it.

```
create table tmp_actors_movies_m2m as
select * 
from actors_movies_m2m m2m
where exists (select 1 from movies_main m where m.movieid = m2m.movieid)

truncate table actors_movies_m2m;  -- back it up first!

insert into actors_movies_m2m 
select * 
from tmp_actors_movies_m2m;

drop table actors_movies_m2m;
```

Note that your question itself indicates a potential design problem. You can avoid orphan records from the start by setting up proper a foreign key with the `on delete cascade` option:

```
create table actors_movies_m2m  (
    ... -- columns here
    movieid int references movies_main (movieid) on delete cascade
);
```

Comment: Would adding an index after the fact (after the table has been populated) have any effect, or does that only work as records are being added. IOW, will indexing be done on already existing records when an index is added?